# MongoDB error when tryin to start up services

Tags: mongodb, server

I recently have been having issues with mongoDB services.
I am running on MacOs Ventura v13.0.1.

I even removed MongoDB from machine and try to re-isntall it.

Install process.

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@6.0
```

Running services

```
brew services start mongodb-communit@6.0
```

Checking services

```
brew services
```

error

```
mongodb-community error  3584 root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Any help would be great. I have been stuck on this and cannot run a a MongoDB server on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is an issue with the launch agent plist file for MongoDB. This file is used by macOS to start MongoDB as a service when your machine boots up.

You can tryp following steps to resolve the issue:

- Stop MongoDB service by running the command `brew services stop mongodb-community@6.0`.
- Remove the launch agent plist file by running the command `rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist`.
- Restart MongoDB service by running the command `brew services restart mongodb-community@6.0`.
- Verify that MongoDB service is running by running the command `brew services` again.

If the issue still persists after following the steps above, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling MongoDB using Homebrew's cleanup command `brew cleanup mongodb-community@6.0` before reinstalling.

Also you can check MongoDB's log files located in `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/` to see if there is any error message that can help you troubleshoot the issue.